# Anyone had issues with subtraction of a long within an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, long-integer, rdd, subtraction

I am having an issue with the subtraction of a long within an RDD to filter out items in the RDD that are within a certain time range.

So my code filters an RDD of case class auctions, with an object of successfulAuctions(Long, Int, String):

```
auctions.filter(it => relevantAuctions(it, successfulAuctions))
```

The successfulAuctions object is made up of a timestamp: Long, an itemID: Int, and a direction: String (BUY/SELL).

The relevantAuctions function basically uses tail recursion to find the auctions in a time range for the exact item and direction.

```
@tailrec
  def relevantAuctions(auction: Auction, successfulAuctions: List[(Long,     String, String)]): Boolean = successfulAuctions match {
    case sample :: xs => if (isRelevantAuction(auction, sample) )    true else relevantAuctions(auction, xs)
    case Nil => false
  }
```

This then feeds into another method in the if statement that checks the timestamp in the sample is within a 10ms range, and the item ID is the same, as is the direction.

```
def isRelevantAuction(auction: Auction, successfulAuction: (Long, String, String)): Boolean = {
(successfulAuction.timestampNanos - auction.timestampNanos) >= 0 &&
  (successfulAuction.timestampNanos - auction.timestampNanos) < 10000000L &&
  auction.itemID == successfulAuction.itemID &&
  auction.direction== successfulAuction.direction
 }
```

I am having issues where the range option is not entirely working. The timestamps I am receiving back are not within the required range. Although the Item ID and direction seems to be working successfully.

The results I am getting are as follows, when I have a timestamp of `1431651108749267459` for the successful auction, I am receiving other auctions of a time GREATER than this, where it should be less.

The auctions I am receiving have the timestamps of:

```
1431651108749326603
1431651108749330732
1431651108749537901
```

Has anyone experienced this phenomenon?

Thanks!

Comment: For an exercise in FP, replace your tailrec function with a fold.

Comment: Hi @zero323 not sure what the above bit of code will do. The code above will only give 0L everytime. `auction.timestampNanos - auction.timestampNanos = 0L` right? Unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to write is  `auction.timestampNanos - successfulAuction.timestampNanos`.

Comment: @zero323 I can't see your original comment. What were you trying to say?

Comment: @Reactormonk would a fold be useful in this situation as I am not outputting a list but a Boolean instead.

Comment: @eboni `fold` generally means folding a Foldable (e.g. a List) into a single element (e.g. a Boolean). Maybe even a `find`.

Comment: If you want only `successfulAuctions` which occurred before the current action the order of values in subtraction should be reversed, shouldn't it? Instead of fold or recursion just use `successfulAuctions.exists` with curried `isRelevantAuction` as a predicate

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to formulate this a fold, any pointers?